# Что значит забурелая?

Tags: словарь

Значение слова.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Забурелая - начавшая буреть или ставшая совсем бурой, серо-коричневой.

Забурелая трава - застарелая, увядшая.

Забурелая ягода - только начавшая краснеть.

Забурелая компания - (переносн.) - компания не первой свежести - хамоватая, принаглевшая, которой закон не писан (закореневшая).